# How to link to a file one level above the current one

Tags: javascript, html, css

In CSS I know that I can reference/link to another file using either of the following:
`photo.jpg` or `./photo.jpg` for a file in the same location as the one I am working in, and `photo-folder/images/photo.jpg` or `./photo-folder/images/photo.jpg` to link a file in one or more directories **below**/inside the parent directory of the one I am working in.

I also know the same idea applies in HTML like `./[href]` or `[href]`.

But I am wondering, let's say the positions of the files in my example are reversed, that is, I want to link to a photo in a directory which is the direct/indirect parent of the file I'm working in. How would I call that file without using the full drive address such as `C:/Users/Username/Code/etc/photo.jpg`, while my working file is `C:/Users/Username/Code/etc/code/file.css`...

How is it done in these languages: HTML, CSS, JS, Python? (You are welcome to answer for other languages, I might need it later! :D)

Side question: is there any technical difference between `./file` and `file`, and would it be preferable to stick to one format over the other (e.g. to prevent problems, for readability, etc)? Though I have never run into any problems using either, or even combining both in the same project...

Comment: [This information](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for this, it helps! but why don't you post directly as an answer? I wonder if it applies in CSS. And it seems to be limited to only one file above the working file.

Comment: Yes, it applies in CSS. Suppose you want to link to a background-image that is two directories above where your CSS file is. `background-image: url('../../photo.jpg');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get to parent directory use `../`, this is "per directory", so if you need access several levels back, you'd need use: `../../../` (for 3 levels)

As of using `./` for current directory - it's redundant

As far as I know this is pretty much applies to all languages, however in `HTML`/`CSS` there is another relative path that can be used to get to the root of the domain: `/` (no dots)
so for example if you open `https://example/some/long/path/file.html` and need access to file at `http://example/file.jpg` you simply put as relative path: `/file.jpg`

Comment: `../` literally means "go up one directory". As such, if you want to move up two levels you need `../../photo.jpg`