Can we link the file that is above the html file you are programming?
Suppose the File structure is this:
root-directory/
│   index.html
│
└── Extension/
    └── childFile.html

Let's say we've got an anchor tag in the childFile that redirects us to the index.html page, how can we do so?
Please gimme a solution to this problem, I kinda mismanaged my project's file system and now I can't figure out how to link pages that are below the hierarchical system of files

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632341/how-to-link-to-a-file-one-level-above-the-current-one

From childFile, a href="../index.html" will link one directory "up" the hierarchy to your root level.
